# Android - Extending ViewGroup than Adding Fragment is showing up Blank

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewgroup

I am extending a `Fragment` called `Scanlist`. It is laid out properly and looks how I want it. Problem is I am unable to `Override onInterceptTouchEvent` on the extended `Fragment`. So I thought of extending `ViewGroup`, `Override onInterceptTouchEvent` and then add my `Fragment` to the `ViewGroup`. When I add my `Fragment` to the `ViewGroup` the `Fragment` is not showing up inside the `ViewGroup`. I know the `ViewGroup` is there because I am able to `Log` the `onInterceptTouchEvent` but the screen is blank.

Here is the Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.scanlist, container, false);
    mRootview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mSharedData = new SharedData(mContext);
    costomListViewArr = mSharedData.getvins();
    Resources res = getResources();

    mList = (ListView)mRootview.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new Scanvinadapter(mActivity, costomListViewArr, res);

    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.setimplements(this);

    ViewGroup vg = new Scanlistview(mContext);
    vg.addView(mRootview);
    return vg;
}
```

Here is the ViewGroup

```
public class Scanlistview extends ViewGroup{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public Scanlistview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        Log.v(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    }
}
```

scanlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flScanlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/vinlist_bg">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:background="@drawable/vinlist_selector"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/vinlist_selector"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: why a custom ViewGroup? override onInterceptTouchEvent in a root container returned by Fragment.getView method

Comment: @pskink not sure how to do that? This gives me the root of the fragment `ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.flScanlist);` but I am not sure how to `setOnInterceptTouchEvent` on vg?

Comment: post R.layout.scanlist layout file

Comment: @pskink ive added it to my question

Comment: so instead of FrameLayout add your custom FrameLayout with overriden method

Comment: @pskink i never looked at it like that, thanks so much works liek a charm, if you want to answer this question let me know, if not I will just delete it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of FrameLayout add your custom FrameLayout with overriden
method, also you don't actually need that FrameLayout as it has only one child,  so you can just place custom ListView in the layout file